# Where did Rey get this lightsaber?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the end scenes of the movie *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, Rey pushes the lightsabers of Leila & Luke inside Tatooine. Then comes the scene of her opening a new lightsaber: Yellow-colored.

Where did she get this lightsaber? Did she make herself a new lightsaber?

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the possible spoiler. Please check if it doesn't change the question you want to ask.

Comment: [Same question on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/224710/98028)

Comment: I am not convinced with the answer here - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/224721/9331

Comment: I’m of the opinion she made it herself. She may have learned how from Luke or from the texts. I think the point of that scene was to convey that Rey had moved on from borrowing inherited lightsabers of a past generation, to making her own and letting the past finally rest.

Comment: I think it’s a traditional rite of passage for a Jedi to make their own lightsaber. Can’t remember where I know this from. Pretty sure it was part of the MMO Star Wars: The Old Republic. I am fairly sure both Anakin and Luke made their own at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, most likely she made it herself per tradition...

While it is not shown on screen, it's often known by non casual *Star Wars* fans, that usually force users, such as the Jedi and the Sith, construct their own lightsabers. Traditionally the Jedi have used "[Jedi Initiation trials](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Initiate_Trials)".

> **The second was not consistent throughout the Order's history.
> Originally, the test consisted of lightsaber construction** using
> crystals provided by the master. As the Order came into a new era
> following the Ruusan Reformation, the trial was altered to test
> self-discipline. Demonstrating competency through meditation or staged
> lightsaber combat with a hood, this test was not so much a
> demonstration in skill so much as technique...

In addition, we have seen Luke Skywalker come to do this, as he has a new lightsaber in *Return of the Jedi*.

> **Darth Vader:** **I see you have constructed a new lightsaber. Your skills
> are complete.** Indeed you are powerful, as the Emperor has foreseen.

<sub>**NOTE:** Star Wars' new theme park, *Galaxy's Edge*, allows visitors to construct their own lightsabers to be able to feel like one is a part of this known process...</sub>

It's about tradition and one's own identity within the Force, as kyber crystals can speak to a light-sided force users. (The dark side usually corrupts the crystal with a "bleeding" process. Darth Vader was tasked to steal the lightsaber of a Jedi who survived Order 66 and bleed its crystal to make it his own!)

#### Wookiepedia (Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker Visual Dictionary):

> [Rey](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rey_Skywalker) returned to Ajan Kloss to celebrate the victory with the
> Resistance and her friends, Dameron and Finn. Afterwards, she traveled
> to the Lars moisture farm on Tatooine, **where she buried Leia's
> lightsaber and the Skywalker lightsaber, using her own newly-crafted
> one in their place**. When a local asked for her name, she forwent
> Palpatine's lineage, going by the name "Rey Skywalker" with the
> blessing of Force-ghosts of Luke and Leia.

So most likely, Rey, now being reborn a Skywalker, has constructed her own, and is allowing some of the past to be laid to rest, as she now comes into her own. It's a symbolic gesture to show the audience who she is and in some ways, plays back into the Force dyad she shared with Kylo Ren, as yellow is quite "light" and her hilt is pretty "dark." She's been made "whole" and is beginning her bigger journey.

---

*What does her new color mean, you might also ask?*

#### **The Rise of Skywalker Opening Crawl:**

> The dead speak! The galaxy has heard a mysterious broadcast, a threat
> of REVENGE in the sinister voice of the late EMPEROR PALPATINE.
>
> GENERAL LEIA ORGANA dispatches secret agents to gather intelligence,
> **while REY, the last hope of the Jedi**, trains for battle against the
> diabolical FIRST ORDER.
>
> Meanwhile, Supreme Leader KYLO REN rages in search of the phantom
> Emperor, determined to destroy any threat to his power.

It's unclear, but it may lean into a spin-off in which Rey (and Finn) will now continue with a New Jedi Order, as this color saber has been associated with a few characters from the previous expanded universe ("Legends") characters who were apart of Luke's [The New Jedi Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Jedi_Order), such as the ongoing adventures of **Kyle Katurn**, in which he eventually ends up with a yellow Lightsaber.

However, there are also [Jedi Temple Guards](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_Guard) ***an ancient heritage*** who wielded **double-bladed** yellow lightsabers, traditionally wore masks, and were Sentinal Jedi Knights dedicated to a higher purpose of the Jedi Order. (A purpose or system of operations that never has been fully revealed, but they did exist during the Prequel era too). This could suggest a much bigger story pertaining to an (Jedi/Sith) origin story or a "bigger" mandate outside of what the Skywalker Saga era showed us.

Comment: The RoS visual dictionary says her quarterstaff is made of a salvaged power conduit - it seems the implication is that it was used in creating the lightsaber

Comment: Cool! I haven't had the chance to pick up my own copy yet. I have had to raid the internet for screen shots and updating Wikipedia entries! :)

Comment: I was in a bookstore and saw it and alllmost took a photo... but figured I’d be breaking some kinda copyright ‍♂️